# accessing local host from emulator

Tags: android, windows, networking, wamp, genymotion

i am using Genymotion emulator which is the most great emulator and the fastest ever, but i am trying to connect to the local host of my computer  since morning, i tried both 192.168.1.30 (taken by cmd>ipconfig>ipv4) and 192.168.56.1 which is used by many genymotion users as they mentioned.. but all what i am getting is this message on the emulator's browser:

```
Forbidden
you don't have permission to access/ on this server
```

it seems like its a matter of permission, some thing related to Wamp server configuration, or may be to firewall or any thing, i just need to create this connection simply..

Answer (score 0):

On an Emulator you can access localhost on `http://10.0.2.2/you_php_script.php`

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to connect to 192.168.56.1.

Make sure that the service that you are running on localhost is bound to the 192.168.56.1 interface.

Make sure that you do not have a firewall running.